# Switch pivot table filter using VBA macro (button)

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I need help with some rather easy macro, but I can't do that. So all I want is to switch between filters - I have two possibilities, by example two colours - black and white, and I only want to have one of them in the moment (I want to add button, so it will work as switch). Here is the situation

[image: pivottable]

I've tried did it with conditional, of course it doesn't work, but hope it will helps you to understand my idea. If one filter is enable, the other one is disabled (so the objects connected with that obviously too).

```
Sub Makro5()

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("colour"). _
    CurrentPage = "(All)"

If ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("colour")
    .PivotItems("black").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("white").Visible = True
    Then ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields ("colour")
    .PivotItems("black").Visible = True
    .PivotItems("white").Visible = False
    Else: ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields ("colour")
    .PivotItems("black").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("white").Visible = True

End Sub
```

Something is wrong with If, because it's on red and I get "Complie error: Syntax error" info

Comment: You can include your code with inline markup, that will make it easier to help. But from your question it's not clear "what doesn't work"

Comment: there is no End If before End Sub

Comment: Also, syntax is If <condition> Then ...Else <Condition> End If . So there is another syntax error by having two lines before the Then that don't form a valid set of test conditions. And there are no line continuations _ used so I'm afraid there are a lot of corrections to this code to make it run.\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have the `Then` on the same line as the `If`. (You *can* use `_` to tell VBA that "code continues on next line")

You also don't have your `And` set up correctly, **and** you are making both "Black" and "White" visible before you check if they are visible?

Try this:

```
Sub ToggleColour()
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("colour")
        If .PivotItems("white").Visible=True Then
            .CurrentPage = "black"
        Else
            .CurrentPage = "white"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Just [Add a Button (Form Control)](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/assign-a-macro-to-a-form-or-a-control-button-d58edd7d-cb04-4964-bead-9c72c843a283) - there was no request to link to the PivotTable_Update event, especially since running the macro would *trigger* that event!

Comment: Wow, works perfectly fine for me! I've made button, use it for my propper data and I'm so happy. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear it!  Please don't forget to click the "Accept answer" button, so that the question is removed from the "unanswered" list

Answer (score 1):

This is what slicers are built for.

Put your cursor inside the the pivottable data area. Then goto insert > slicer > and choose `colour`. You will then have a slicer which will allow you to select either or. I don't know if you can disable multiselect in current excel version so user could press ctrl and select both. But this seems a simple way.

Or you could run code such as the following and then user just types in Black or White in to field and filter is applied:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim pvt As PivotTable

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet3")
    Set pvt = ws.PivotTables("PivotTable3")

    Dim pvtField As PivotField
    Dim item As Long
    Dim item2 As Long

    Set pvtField = pvt.PivotFields("Colour")

    pvtField.EnableItemSelection = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! Of course, I use slicers day by day, but I also want to start making macro, so that was the point.